# My script encounters an error while clicking links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in association with selenium to initiate clicks on some links connected to each profile out of a webpage. My script is doing good for the first link. As there is no valid links (all of them are javascript links) connected to each profile, I had to do the clicking. However, when it is supposed to click on the next linkk and so on, It throws an error `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. If It were not for clicking, I could have easily navigated to each profile without having that error following the logic I applied within my script. In case of clicking links cyclically, I don't find any idea to move along.

What can I do now to get rid of that error and click all the links?

This is my try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def search_links(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    items = [item for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main table tr a"))) if "#" not in item.get_attribute("href")]
    for item in items:
        item.click() #The error is thrown here as soon as the script goes for the second click
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://intraweb.stockton.edu/eyos/page.cfm?siteID=58&pageID=7&action=dirmain&type=FAC&display=basic"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        search_links(driver,url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: When you click the first item you are navigating away from the items you are trying to iterate

Comment: Right you are @Ywapom. I know the reason as well but what I don't know is the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
def search_links(driver,link):
driver.get(link)
items = [item for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main table tr a"))) if "#" not in item.get_attribute("href")]
for i in range(0, len(items)):
    items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#main table tr a")
    items[i].click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("back to directory").click()
    i = i+1;
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot @chaitanya anne. It works. It takes a lot of time but works.

Answer (score 0):

The list of items you are iterating over contains WebElements.  As soon as you `click()` one, you trigger navigation which makes all of the original WebElements stale (because you have navigated away from the DOM they were attached to).

As a workaround, you could get all the href url's from the elements and use those.  Since they don't contain state, it won't matter what page you are on.  So rather than clicking, you could do something like:

```
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main table tr a")))
hrefs = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in elements if "#" not in item.get_attribute("href")]
for href in hrefs:
    driver.get(href)
```

Comment: How come this type of links `javascript:document.form792.submit();` can be navigated? I've clearly mentioned in my question that they are javascript links. Thanks.